# How to use transform to align legend in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have created a discrete legend using HTML, but I am struggling with trying to get the legend title to align correctly, irrespective of the length of the text within the title.

Here is an example of what it looks like in my app for a short title

[image]

... whereas this is what it is like for a longer title

[image]

Below is an attempt at a minimal working example

```css
/* Split the screen in half */
.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Control the left side */
.left {
  left: 0;
}

/* Control the right side */
.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: #999;
}
.box{
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
}

.my-legend .legend-title {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
}
.my-legend .legend-scale ul {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
.my-legend .legend-scale ul li {
    text-align: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.my-legend ul.legend-labels li span {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 45px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="content">

  <!-- Image Panel -->
  <div class="split left" style="position: relative; height: 800px">

    <!-- This is a dynamically generated panel ... but just black here as example -->
    <div id="imagePanel" class="box"></div> 

    <!-- Legend entries -->
    <div class='my-legend' 
         style="position:absolute; 
                right: 10%; top: 50%;
                transform-box: fill-box; 
                transform: translate(0%,-50%);">

      <div class='legend-scale'>
        <ul class='legend-labels'>
          <li> <b>0</b> &nbsp; <span style="background: rgb(128,64,0)">   </span> </li>
          <li> <b>1</b> &nbsp; <span style="background: rgb(251,255,128)"></span> </li>
          <li> <b>2</b> &nbsp; <span style="background: rgb(55,128,0)">   </span> </li>
          <li> <b>3</b> &nbsp; <span style="background: rgb(128,255,140)"></span> </li>
          <li> <b>4</b> &nbsp; <span style="background: rgb(0,128,81)">   </span> </li>
          <li> <b>5</b> &nbsp; <span style="background: rgb(128,234,255)"></span> </li>
          <li> <b>6</b> &nbsp; <span style="background: rgb(0,38,128)">   </span> </li>
          <li> <b>7</b> &nbsp; <span style="background: rgb(157,128,255)"></span> </li>
          <li> <b>8</b> &nbsp; <span style="background: rgb(98,0,128)">   </span> </li>
          <li> <b>9</b> &nbsp; <span style="background: rgb(255,128,217)"></span> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Legend Title -->
    <div class='my-legend' 
         style="position:absolute; 
                right: 0; top: 50%; 
                transform-box: fill-box; 
                transform: translate(0%,-50%); 
                transform: rotate(-90deg)">

      <div class='legend-title' >True Label</div>      
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <div class="split right" id="controlsPanel" >      
    Some Other Panel will go here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please create a snippet with the full HTML, legends etc. compiled

Comment: @ZachJensz, an example JS Fiddle was added. Thanks

Comment: BTW you can add snippets directly here in SO with the `<>` button.

Comment: I don't have the time for a complete analysis, but you probably should avoid `position: absolute`. Place the two parts side-by-side with "normal" methods such as flex or grid.

Comment: @RoToRa The legend tick names can change too in my application, so by placing the legend beside the plotting pane could end up reducing the plotting pane too much. Overlay is better in my instance. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen to the text when it has to wrap onto multiple lines

Comment: Just reading through these comments again... You want the legend title to be an overlay, but you don't want it to overlap... Can you be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writing-mode` should sidestep the width/height headache caused by rotating, but I can't find a way to avoid having to rotate by 180 to flip it the way you want.

Edit: Replaced absolute/relative positioning with grid, positioned legend text without overlay.

```css
/* Split the screen in half */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.left {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4fr min-content 1fr;
  background-color: black;
}

.right {
  background-color: #999;
}

.legend-title {
  max-height: 40ch;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: red;
}

.my-legend .legend-scale ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.my-legend .legend-scale ul li {
  text-align: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.my-legend ul.legend-labels li span {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  height: 45px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="content">
  <!-- Image Panel -->
  <div class="split left">
    <!-- This is a dynamically generated panel ... but just black here as example -->
    <div id="imagePanel" class="box"></div>
    <!-- Legend entries -->
    <div class='my-legend'>
      <div class='legend-scale'>
        <ul class='legend-labels'>
          <li><b>0</b>&nbsp;<span style="background: rgb(128,64,0)"></span></li>
          <li><b>1</b>&nbsp;<span style="background: rgb(251,255,128)"></span></li>
          <li><b>2</b>&nbsp;<span style="background: rgb(55,128,0)"></span></li>
          <li><b>3</b>&nbsp;<span style="background: rgb(128,255,140)"></span></li>
          <li><b>4</b>&nbsp;<span style="background: rgb(0,128,81)"></span></li>
          <li><b>5</b>&nbsp;<span style="background: rgb(128,234,255)"></span></li>
          <li><b>6</b>&nbsp;<span style="background: rgb(0,38,128)"></span></li>
          <li><b>7</b>&nbsp;<span style="background: rgb(157,128,255)"></span></li>
          <li><b>8</b>&nbsp;<span style="background: rgb(98,0,128)"></span></li>
          <li><b>9</b>&nbsp;<span style="background: rgb(255,128,217)"></span> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Legend Title -->
    <div class='legend-title'>True Label test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</div>

  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <div id="controlsPanel" class="split right">
    Some Other Panel will go here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your snippet, the title still overlaps the legend entries. As shown above, I would need this to be on the right hand side of the entries. Also, why does it automatically go onto two lines rather than just all on the one line?

Comment: @KevinSweeney I'll update with better explanation

Comment: I had no idea why it was going onto two lines, not that familiar with relative/absolute positioning. I changed it all out for modern grid which hopefully works for you.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to make some minor changes for my actual code as was formatted slightly different than this example, but it now works. The changes to `.legend-title` is what I needed! Thank you